# Numpy where to replace if else, more than 3 arguments in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
df = {'Fruit':['Apple','Banana','Cherries','Dragonfruit','Elderberry']}
pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I would like to create a new column based on the fruit variable.

Expected Output:

```
Fruit             Quantity
Apple                 10
Banana                 5
Cherries               3
Dragonfruit            2
Elderberry             1
```

Code:

````
df['Quantity']= np.where(df['Fruit']=='Apple',10, df['Fruit']=='Banana',5,
df['Fruit']=='Cherries',3,df['Fruit']=='Dragonfruit',2,1)
```

shows the error:
TypeError: where() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 9 were given
````

Comment: `np.select((cond1, cond2), (select1, select2), default)`

Answer (score 1):

Like @Quang mentioned in the comments, use select function:

```
df['Quantity']= np.select((df['Fruit']=='Apple',df['Fruit']=='Banana',df['Fruit']=='Cherries',df['Fruit']=='Dragonfruit'),(10,5,3,2),1)
```

output:

```
         Fruit  Quantity
0        Apple        10
1       Banana         5
2     Cherries         3
3  Dragonfruit         2
4   Elderberry         1
```